# JPA: Outside container transaction not committing

Tags: java, maven, jpa, junit, persistence

I am testing JPA for my application.

The connection to the DB seems successfull,

```
Running com.vgorcinschi.rimmanew.ejbs.OutsideContainerJpaTests 
[EL Info]: 2015-12-25 07:32:26.202--ServerSession(1302779492)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd
[EL Info]: connection: 2015-12-25 07:32:26.493--ServerSession(1302779492)--file:/home/vgorcinschi/NetBeansProjects/RimmaNew/target/classes/_outsideContainer login successful
```

but the data is not persisting.

Because my app runs on GlassFish and I am trying JUnit tests outside container, I have created a second persistence-unit. This is what inside persistence.xml file (note that I have masked my credentials to the DB):

```
<persistence-unit name="outsideContainer" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                  value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/beaty_shop?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="**********"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="*************"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

This is the singleton method that returns the EntityManagerFactory:

```
public static EntityManagerFactory getUniqueInstance() {
    if (uniqueInstance == null) {
        synchronized (EntityManagerFactoryProvider.class) {
            if (uniqueInstance == null) {
                uniqueInstance = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("outsideContainer");
            }
        }
    }
    return uniqueInstance;
}
```

This is the Repository Stub which doesn't throw exceptions, but which also doesn't persist data to DB.The transaction is initiated and committed...

```
public class JpaAppointmentRepositoryStub implements AppointmentRepository {



  private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    public JpaAppointmentRepositoryStub(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        this.emf = emf;
    }

    public JpaAppointmentRepositoryStub() {
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Appointment appointment) {
        EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction trans = em.getTransaction();
        try {
            trans.begin();
            em.persist(appointment);
            trans.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            trans.rollback();
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Appointment appointment) {
        EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        em.merge(appointment);
    }

    @Override
    public Appointment get(long id) {
        EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        try {
            return em.find(Appointment.class, id);
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            return null;
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }


}
```

A transaction from an EntityManager is not null:

```
@Test
public void aTransactionIsNotNull(){
    EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction trans = em.getTransaction();
    assertNotNull(trans);
    em.close();
}
```

Last interesting and useful piece of information is that Repository is being "operated" by a Service class that has a single method for Repository's save and update operation. So the only drawback should be just in opening and closing two entity managers on each call:

```
public class OutsideContainerAppointmentService implements AppointmentService{
private final AppointmentRepository repository;
...
@Override
    public void save(Appointment appointment) {
        if (findById(appointment.getId()) != null) 
            repository.update(appointment);
        else 
            repository.add(appointment);        
    }
...
}
```

MySQL Connector/J is in the test dependencies of this Maven project (but as login is successful this is not an issue).

So what do you think might be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Even though it doesn't make sense (for at least so far) the right solution is this.

I have added the .joinTransaction() method and everything started working fine.

```
    @Override
    public void add(Appointment appointment) {
        EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction trans = em.getTransaction();
        trans.begin();
        try {
                //this is the line that I have added                
                em.joinTransaction();
                em.persist(appointment);
                trans.commit();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                trans.rollback();
            } finally {
                em.close();
            }
        }
```

But according to [JPA wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Transactions#Join_Transaction) I shouldn't be using .joinTransaction() in this case:

> joinTransaction is only used with JTA managed EntityManagers (JTA
>   transaction-type in persistence.xml). For RESOURCE_LOCAL
>   EntityManagers you can just commit the JPA transaction whenever you
>   desire.

Another "bug" that I had to fix was to transfer the `appointmentService.save(dummy);` outside the setUp() method and inside a @Test annotated method. That was the reason I started getting double writes into the DB.